# Issues in lemmatization (nltk)

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am using nltk lemmatizer as follows.

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
mystring = "the sand rock needed to be mixed and shaked well before using it for construction works"
splits=mystring.split()
mystring = " ".join(lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in splits)
print(mystring)
```

I am expecting the output to be

```
sand rock need to be mix and shake well before use it for construction work
```

However, in the output I get (mentioned below) it seems like words such as `needed, mixed, shaked, using` have not changed to its base form.

```
sand rock needed to be mixed and shaked well before using it for construction work
```

Is there a way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the second last line with this.

```
mystring = " ".join(lemmatizer.lemmatize(w,pos ='v') for w in splits)
```

pos is part of speech tag.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.